# app not working when i check embed air runtime with application

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, flash-cs6

I am using adobe flash professional cs6 to create an android app. When i publish the app with **GET AIR RUNTIME FROM GOOGLE MARKET**, the app is working. But When i check **EMBED AIR RUNTIME WITH APPLICATION**  the app is not opening or working(**ERROR MESSAGE:** unfortunately app has stoped.)

So, how to make the app work with ***embed air runtime with application checked***

**Note:** I want to embed air runtime with application because i dont want user to download anything else after downloading my app to make my app work.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your Adobe AIR SDK. Latest https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html you can get here.

Beta is here https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/air/AIRSDK_Compiler.zip for Windows and https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/air/AIRSDK_Compiler.tbz2 here for MacOS

Comment: Well, updating fixed the issue. thanx.